# Questions about 〜にあたって, 驚かされた, and 関係者何人か

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, verbs, expressions

> 当時の**関係者何人かにあたって**記憶を確かめてみたが、人の記憶の欠落部分というのは、捏造で補われる仕組みになっているらしく、共通の体験が、しばしば、お互いに矛盾する記憶になっていることに**驚かされた**。

1. What does “にあたって” mean there?
2. “驚かされた” is referring to what/whom exactly?
3. Does “関係者何人か” mean “Some people of the authorized personnel”?

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @istrasci's answer:

あたる here is [the 4th entry in the article on goo 辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/4694/m0u/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B/), basically "investigate" or "observe".

Answer (score 0):

The whole sentence basically translates to something like

> (I) Tried to verify the memories of the related parties of/at the time, but I was surprised to learn that when it comes to the "holes" in the human memory, their recollections of the same/shared experience were inconsistent with each other, almost as if it was all setup -- (the memories) fabricated to complement one another.

- `関係者何人か` means "several of the people related to <whatever the context is about>".
- The `驚かされた` is referring to whoever "speaking" that sentence; presumably the person that questioned these people about their memories of whatever happened.

I know what `〜にあたって` means when it has the sense of `〜の時`, but that doesn't make sense here.  So I'm not sure why it is used in this sentence.

Comment: Perhaps it's using some meaning of 当たる outside of the phrase にあたって？

Comment: I don't agree with the "almost as if it was all setup -- fabricated" part. Where do you get this from?

Comment: Does this help?  
人の記憶の欠落部分というのは、捏造で補われる仕組みになっているらしく => "(because of the way the mind works,) the holes in people's memories tend to be filled by false memories."